# Upgrading already existing app on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I have uploaded an app on Google Play already. I need to scrap this existing project and create a new one and upload it as v 0.2 ? I have the old self signed certificate. What should I do in order to upload a whole new app as new version ?

Comment: can you please explain a bit more.. i couldnt understand..@

Comment: Use the same package name and the same signing certificate as for the old app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check your using the same name package and also
you must have the same key (release/debug), because the key is what identifie your app, then if you change or register your app with a new key then google play will think it's a new App, and won't override the old one, also don't forget to change the `android:versionCode` & `android:versionName` in the manifest.

You should read this post about what can't change once the app is published [Things that cannot change](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely change package names, you will also have to change play store listings.

If you want to save your listing, and just change apks, all you need to do is update version code in your manifest file
Change the code from (for example)

```
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="0.1"
```

To:

```
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="ANYTHING YOU WANT"
```